# Running Jar file as command without java -jar prefix

Tags: java, command-line, jar

I am developing an app that takes arguments like usual command. For example -h option prints help like this:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ java -jar my.jar -h
usage: My App
 -d,--download-to <arg>   Download path
 -h,--help                Shows this help
```

I am wondering if it is possible to run jar file from command line without using java -jar prefix?

Like this:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ my.jar -h
usage: My App
 -d,--download-to <arg>   Download path
 -h,--help                Shows this help
```

Comment: You  could create a batch file and run that instead.

Comment: you could use spring-boot when you build your app and configure the spring-boot-maven-plugin to create a ‘fully executable’ jar, https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html

Answer (score 2):

Try set command alias: `alias myjar='java -jar my.jar'`